# Numerical integration of the dataset of a function

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, numerics, integration, calculus

The energy equation for a spherically symmetric system is given by
$$\mathscr{E}=\frac{v^2(r)}{2}+\frac{c_s^2(r)}{\gamma-1}+\phi(r)$$
where $\mathscr{E}$ is the total energy, $v$ is the velocity of fluid, $c_s$ is the speed of sound and $\phi$ is the potential energy. The radial force is obtained as the derivative of the potential energy, i.e., $f(r)=-\phi'(r)$, where the prime means derivative wrt $r$.

One can obtain the derivative of the equation as follows:
$$\mathscr{E}'=vv'+\frac{2c_sc_s'}{\gamma-1}+\phi'$$

I am working in hydrodynamics of the system where I have an expression for $f(r)$ which is too complicated to integrate as the integral involves complex roots (the expression for $f(r)$ is the integrand in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3440491/646930)). Using other constraints of the problem, the first two terms of the second equation can be expressed in  terms of $\phi'$.  This means that the second equation can be written as a function of $\phi'$(or equivalently $f(r)$). Now we can easily plot the equation
$$\mathscr{E}'=\mathscr{E}'(f(r))=\mathscr{E}'(r)$$
The second equality is evident as $f(r)$ is a function of only $r$.

**MY QUESTION:**

Since $\mathscr{E}'(r)$ is a function of $r$, we can plot this function and obtain the dataset for a whole range of $r$. So is it possible to numerically integrate $\mathscr{E}'(r)$ using the dataset?

I am not sure whether such a numerical integration of a dataset is possible.

Comment: As a point to clarify, the *energy* is the integral over the expression you have in the first formula. The first formula is really just an energy *density*. That also explains the funny second formula you have which does not seem to originate from the first by differentiation.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Here $\mathscr{E}$ is actually the specific energy of a fluid element in the Bondi flow model of spherical accretion in astrophysics. Then one can perform sonic point analysis at a critical point to express both $v$ and $c_s$ in terms of $\phi'$. The similar calculations for a Newtonian model is done in page-10 of the following link: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=3GcGCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: No, it's still only an energy *density* :-)

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you are asking whether you have values for a function $h'(r)$ at points $r_i$, you can obtain an approximation of $h(r)$. The answer is of course yes: If you connect the points $(r_i,h'(r_i))$ by a piecewise linear curve, then you can integrate that to obtain a piecewise quadratic approximation of $h(r)$.

You can be more accurate if you connect the points $(r_i,h'(r_i))$ through, for example, a spline curve.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for answering. I would like to try the spline curve method.